# Google+ SIgnin doesn't back to my application

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I did create a Console Project in Google site and get the Client ID..

I did implement the signin button in my application and it works, but after login it doesn't back to my application, it go to google site.

here is my code:

```
   signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, // defined in GTLPlusConstants.h
                     nil];
    signIn.delegate = self;

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
{
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                             annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: Take a look at that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092644/google-plus-api-doesnt-return-to-app-on-login

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you called for authentication method.

Add method call at the end, like this:

```
signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, // defined in GTLPlusConstants.h
                 nil];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn authenticate];
```