# Google plus API doesn't return to app on login

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-api, google-plus

Obviously I must be missing something.

When I press my Google + button, it opens up safari and prompts for the login.  Everything is fine until I complete the login procress.  Safari tells me "Cannot open the Page -- Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid".  It never takes me back to my app, but keeps Safari open and goes to google.com.

I was thinking this would take care of that, but break points aren't ever going off in this method.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding how it works.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take look to the Bundle Identifier that is in your project and that you have registered with https://code.google.com/apis/console . Both of them should be same. After that make sure also you have set that same URL Schemes in URL Types in your application plist file.

Comment: I award you 3 trillion kudos.  You were absolutely right about the URL scheme in the .plist.  That fixed it.

Comment: Totally missed it in the working project. Saved my day. Thanks. :)

Comment: 1 Amazing i like it Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today. I finally compared the [sample app (included w/ SDK)](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/getting-started#before_you_begin)  line by line before I figured my problem out.

I didn't realize the ClientID found in the Developers Console was in standard domain name order while the URL Scheme for 1 of the 2 URL Types in the project settings (Info.plist) needs to be in reverse domain name notation

**ClientID** in *Developers Console* is `[guid].apps.googleusercontent.com`

**URL Scheme** in *Info.plist* is `com.googleusercontent.apps.[guid]`